# How to call custom action in controller(laravel) using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.

I have a custom action in my controller. By custom I mean it is not used by the resource object in angular. The following is the code of my controller.

```
class ServicesController extends Controller {
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

public function extras()
    {
         // code here
    }
}
```

This is my service code in the angular script.

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('bam')
        .factory('myservice', myservice);

    function myservice($resource) {

        // ngResource call to the API for the users
        var Serviceb = $resource('services', {}, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            extras: {
                method: 'GET',
                action: 'extras'
            }
        });
     function getExtras(){
            return Serviceb.query().$promise.then(function(results) {
                return results;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
 }

})();
```

Now, the `query()` here will send the request to the index method in the laravel controller. How will I access the `extras()` action in the `getExtras()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there try out the example below I tried to use what you have in your question, and added a few other custom endpoints as examples.  You'll want a base URL set up similarly to the example so you can feed it an id out of your payload so $resource can set up your base CRUD.  Otherwise to make custom routes using the same resource endpoint you can add some extra actions like you have in your question, but apply your customization on the base endpoints URL.

```
.factory('ServicesResource', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {

        // Parameters used in URL if found in payload
        var paramDefaults = {
            id: '@id',
            param: '@param'
        }

        // Additional RESTful endpoints above base CRUD already in $resource
        var actions = {

            custom1: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/services/custom',
            },
            custom2: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/services/custom/:param',
            },
            extras: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/services/extras' 
            }
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        }

        // Default URL for base CRUD endpoints like get, save, etc
        return $resource('/api/services/:id', paramDefaults, actions);
    }])
```

Now you can dependency inject the factory and use it like this:

```
var payload = {param:'someParam'};

ServicesResource.custom(payload).$promise.then(function(response){

    // handle success

}, function(reason) {

    // handle error
});
```

Or for Extras:

```
ServicesResource.extras().$promise.then(function(response){

    // Handle success

}, function(reason) {

    // Handle error
});
```

In Laravel you're route might be something like this:

```
Route::get('services/{param}/custom', 'ServicesController@custom');
```

Or for extras like this:

```
Route::get('services/extras', 'ServicesController@extras');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted using `$http`.

```
function getExtras(){
  return $http.get('/services/extras').success(function (results) {
      return results;
  });
}
```

But, that would be nice if anyone suggest me how to do it with `Serviceb.query().$promise.then`.